# Are calculated quantities a part of the Model, View or Controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Say I have a Model-View-Controller type application. The model is a car with an engine and tires etc. The speed of the car is a derived/calculated non-persistent quantity that depends on the engine and tires.

**Should the speed be a part of the model? Or should it be a part of the view?**

This far I have let the speed be a part of the view (because it is not persisted and it is not used by the model for anything). But I find that I increasingly have to have many views showing the speed (overview and detail view for example). This results in that I end up either passing a `SpeedCalculator` class around everywhere in addition to the model or creating `getSpeedCalculator` type accessors in my views, which leads me to believe that the calculated quantities should be a part of the model.

But I would like to have some input on this.

Comment: Short answer is the model. It is not persistence data but still part of the data that could be represented in different views as the car info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with your feeling and establish that attribute as a synthetic field in your model. So no extra physical field, but put the derivation function down as a getter. In my opinion that's OK, because that getter does only little more than a really dumb field accessor, and the definition of the value appears to be the same throughout your application and especially is independent of the view it appears in.

If the calculation will ever be dependent on the view, I'd suggest putting down the derivation functions as a Utility on the controller level, so this really becomes an architectural question based on your plans/requirements.